# Blank page when debuggin with xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using php storm and xdebug extenstion to debug my php code, when I activate debugging at the end of the request i see white page, with no respone, if I deactivate the debuggger helper, the page renders successfully.

Is it normal?

Comment: Any entries in the http servers error log? Have you tried taking a look at the delivered html pages source code? Does the browser finish loading or is it running into a timeout?

Comment: when you abort a run in xdebug, then the request is killed at the moment. The consequence is normally a blank page (if you have for example a running transaction with Zend_Db you get an exception)

Comment: I'm not aborting... just proceed execution

Comment: I am encountering this now, and have in the past. Its very frustrating. The last time I found that the version of XDebug that I was using was known for this problem. The solution was to go back a version. About to try that now...

Comment: The big clue is that without XDebug on, the blank page *does not occur*

Comment: Hello there in 2017 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings these values for xdebug in php.ini helped me:

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

I had a problem where Vagrant would not be friends with Phpstorm. I was able to make a breakpoint on the first line of the script, but it dit not step further and just returned a blank line.

Comment: I used the same configuration  as  above, but issue still exists